# what is the probabilty that sum of two random numbers between A and B is less than third number C

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, contest-math, uniform-distribution

> What is the probabilty that sum of two random numbers uniformly distributed in $[A,B]$ is less than a fixed $C$?

I have tried answering this question using graph method to find the area under the curve, but I couldn't find out the answer despite long hours of efforts. Can someone help?

Comment: What's the random distribution of the three numbers? Uniform ?

Comment: @Tryss uniform distribution

Comment: And is $C$ fixed or random?

Comment: @Tryss  C is a fixed number

Comment: Are these integers? Do you have a range of values from which you choose them?

Comment: @ZeroXLR A and B is the range

Comment: Ok ok. And the random numbers are integers between $A$ and $B$? If they are real numbers instead, you can refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed do this graphically. Consider A=0 and B=1 for simplicity. Your situation can be represented by this :

[image]

So the probability you want is the area of the colored area:

$$P( X+Y > C) = 1-\frac{C^2}{2}$$

Edit : with the correct graph it's better

Comment: Now it's correct

Comment: Only on the range 0<C<min(A,B).

Comment: @Tryss  what about other intervals when ( c > min(a,b) && c <= max(a,b) )and other case( c < (a+b) && c > max(a,b) )

Comment: @Did  can u explain for  other intervals when ( c > min(a,b) && c <= max(a,b) )and other case( c < (a+b) && c > max(a,b) )

Comment: I will not, for the simple reason that the diagram in @Tryss' answer tells everything there is to say (when A=B, but this is already something), if only one cares to look at it carefully. That you did not care to do so (obviously), points at your question itself, posted with no personal input whatsoever, in contradiction with the guidelines of the site.

Comment: *Please replace "when A=B" by "when A=0 and B=1".